# AuthGuard of @nestjs/passport with setMetaData

Tags: nestjs, passport.js

I have a project requirement in which I want to disallow some of the API endpoints will not need the authentication. From search, I found that I need to use setMetadata from NestJS library. As I am using `@nestjs/passport` for the authentication I don't know how to implement setMetadata.

I have the following code:

sessionKey.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class SessionKeyAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('sessionKey') {}
```

In controller file

```
@Controller('api/deployments')
// comment the line below to stop authentication
@UseGuards(SessionKeyAuthGuard)
@UseInterceptors(PreRequestCacheInterceptor)
@UseInterceptors(PostRequsetCachingInterceptor)
export class AppDeployController {
     // API methods
}
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 2):

Create a decorator to set metadata

```
export const Public = () => SetMetadata('IS_PUBLIC', true);
```

In your controller, use the decorator on the route to allow public access

```
export class AuthController {    
  @Public()
  @Post('/login')
  login() {
    
  }
}
```

In your guard, check the metadata via:

```
const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>('IS_PUBLIC', [
  context.getHandler(),
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sopheak for your response. I have solved with other approach.